# Worries about Groovy

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, camera-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am swing between Groovy and Fuerte. I have been using Fuerte for a while, but want to try Groovy now. It seems that ROS is neither forward compatible or backward compatible. Is it possible such case happen: One camera driver works on Fuerte but won't work on Groovy??

Or are there any other critical issues if I transfer to Groovy?

Thank you very much for your answers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60033/worries-about-groovy/) by [Maximusone](https://answers.ros.org/users/4616/maximusone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-04-04**:
Which camera driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding the cameras. Upgrading ROS should not give any problems unless you upgrade OS as well. All of the camera packages in ROS I am aware of are either rely on OpenCV, Video4Linux or GStreamer and if these can get an access to device you would not have any problems.

It is also possible that some specific packages are not ported to Groovy API yet, but I believe the vast majority of those you may need are ready.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maximusone](https://answers.ros.org/users/4616/maximusone/) on 2013-04-04**:
Thank you so much for your answer, Boris. My understanding from your words is that the functions we usuallly need won't affect us when transfering to Groovy, like drivers for hardwares, navigation packages, etc.  right?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-05**:
The things you mention work fine on Groovy. Almost all released Ubuntu packages are available: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/groovy.html